# How do you install pip with Python 3.8?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I was wondering how you install pip with the newest version of Python which is 3.8. I try to put in curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py into the command line but I get a syntax error that looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Ivn.png) I was wondering if someone can tell me what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't have to install PIP, it is distributed with python. How did you install python? You aren't trying to use your *system* python, are you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the that code on the *shell command line*, not inside Python.

But apart from that there’s usually a better way to install pip, refer to the [official instructions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to run curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py in your terminal not in the python console.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your command prompt, `cd` to the location of the `pip.exe` or `pip3.exe` from the Python 3.8 package. There, you can enter in your command prompt: `pip install something` or `pip2 install something`.